# In a pivot table - how can I add a dimension in columns (in addition to the dimensional rows)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple data set, I would like to have 2 dimensions in the rows.
And also a dimension in the column.

I have a regular pivot table and I would like to take one of the dimensions (week) to be a dimension in the column side (above all the metrics), so I will have 2 metrics (cost, installs) for each week.

/* agg table */

`df2Group = df2.groupby(['os','Campaign ID','week']).agg({'cost_plus_fee':'sum',                                          'installs':'sum'})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html), [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with `rename` first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'os':['andriod'] * 10,
         'Campaign ID':[103292] * 5 +[103293] * 5,
         'week':[22,23,24] * 3 + [22],
         'cost_plus_fee':[1,3,5,7,1,0,4,5,6,3],
         'installs':[5,3,6,9,2,4,2,5,8,4]
})
print (df2)
        os  Campaign ID  week  cost_plus_fee  installs
0  andriod       103292    22              1         5
1  andriod       103292    23              3         3
2  andriod       103292    24              5         6
3  andriod       103292    22              7         9
4  andriod       103292    23              1         2
5  andriod       103293    24              0         4
6  andriod       103293    22              4         2
7  andriod       103293    23              5         5
8  andriod       103293    24              6         8
9  andriod       103293    22              3         4
```

---

```
df2Group = (df2.groupby(['os','Campaign ID','week'])
               .agg({'cost_plus_fee':'sum', 'installs':'sum'})
               .unstack()
               .swaplevel(1,0, axis=1)  
               .sort_index(axis=1, level=0)
               .rename(columns = lambda x: f'week {x}', level=0))
print (df2Group)
  week                      week 22                week 23           \
                    cost_plus_fee installs cost_plus_fee installs   
os      Campaign ID                                                 
andriod 103292                  8       14             4        5   
        103293                  7        6             5        5   

week                      week 24           
                    cost_plus_fee installs  
os      Campaign ID                         
andriod 103292                  5        6  
        103293                  6       12
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, one small thing can you make the metrics together and not separately?

meaning: week 22: {cost, installs} , week 23 {cost, installs} 
and not like now cost :{week 22, 23, 24} installs {week 22, 23, 24}

Comment: @ornachshon - Done. Btw, one small advice - [Better don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: It's not working.
Thanks for the tip, I did follow the guide but I'm still new so I will try to learn from your advice.
Thank you so much.

Comment: @ornachshon - Can you add output from my solution to answer? Because not sure if understand what need. Thank you.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xtuF37bOqUU5j1W4KhkgaK-abPmZVDhy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ornachshon - Sorry, no permission

Comment: You have permission now.